# How to prevent callback event occur twice?

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

Hi this is my web3 code

```
events.watch(function (error,result){
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error:'+JSON.stringify(error));
                res.send({'status':0,'message':error});
            }else{
                console.log('Result:'+JSON.stringify(result));
                res.send({'status':1,'message':result});

            }
        });
```

Here when ever an event occurs it trigger the watch function. But the problem is, it callback the function, twice. How can I prevent this? In every discussion they just said I fixed and closed the thread. What is the solution to stop triggering twice? I'm using web3 0.20.0. Thank you.

Comment: You're likely processing more than one event. Have you checked to see that the events are what you're expecting?  Can you scope the `watch` to only the event(s) you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hash list based on the transaction's hash and make sure it was not processed before running the code